# How do I render/preview AngularJS custom directives in a CKEditor instance

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I would like to use AngularJS custom directives inside a CKEditor instance and see it on the preview real time.

Like for example, I have a custom directive like so:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('myTest', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'Test'
  };
});
```

And I want to be able to add

```
<my-test></my-test>
```

inside my CKEditor source view, and it will show as

```
Test
```

inside the GUI preview.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: have to use `$compile` on the editor instance `getData()`

Comment: could you please expound on that @charlietfl

Comment: @charlietfl I am not able to show rendered angularjs directives on a separate preview area using  the example here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile